# Performing an assertion about an object argument in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

How do I perform an assertion about an object argument in Jasmine?

I want to write something like the following pseudocode:

```
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWithAnObjectMatching(expectation);
```

Or do I have to write my own custom matcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining(expectedArg));
```